# Microsoft MAUI : How can you create reports in MAUI that opens in new window?

Tags: xamarin, report, maui

How can you create dynamic reports in MAUI that open in a new window?

Comment: "best" is a matter of opinion and off topic on SO

Comment: and "dynamic reports" is incredibly vague and uselessly broad as a requirement

Comment: Hi Jason. I had challenges with my development and Microsoft answered my questions. I am giving back this knowledge to the community so they can find the answers.

Comment: Is there a way to use reportviwer? in a maui WINDOWS app ?

Answer (score 0):

I got a response from Microsoft.

" Regarding creating reports, if you don’t want to do a PDF with a commercial solution of open source, then how about using HTML/CSS? You can pre-style a template document, load that into memory, merge your custom content or data, and then open that in a window with a WebView (or BlazorWebView if you prefer Razor). That may print well. "

Feel free to share If you have additional solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DevExpress Reports: [Use Reporting Tools in .NET MAUI Applications (macOS, iOS, Android)](https://docs.devexpress.com/XtraReports/404425/dot-net-maui-reporting/use-reporting-in-maui-apps)

They enable you to generate a report based on your data source and export it to multiple formats, such as PDF, XLS, and DOC and [others](https://docs.devexpress.com/XtraReports/1302/detailed-guide-to-devexpress-reporting/store-and-distribute-reports/export-reports?p=netframework).